# String dates comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

So, I have two variables and one function:

```js
 function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
  }
  
 const dateToCompare=moment.utc(endDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
 const maximum=moment.utc(addDays(new Date(),14)).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

However, I do not know how to compare them, since they are now formatted as strings, but at the same time new Date(dateToCompare) doesn't work.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: _"I do not know how to compare them, since they are now formatted as strings"_ - Then don't make them strings... o.O

Comment: And why do you mix momentjs with regular `Date` stuff?

Comment: Original dates also have the timestamp. And I only need to compare the dates, without including timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using built–in methods to add days when you are using moment.js?  Consider:

```
let maximum = moment.utc().add('day',14).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

To set a date to the start of a day, use the moment.js [*startOf*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) method:

```
let maximum = moment.utc().add('day',14).startOf('day')
let dateToCompare = moment.utc(endDate).startOf('day')
```

You can compare the dates as strings if formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, or just leave them as moment objects and compare those using [*isSame*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), [*isAfter*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), [*isSameOrBefore*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/), etc.

When parsing strings as in:

```
const dateToCompare=moment.utc(endDate)
```

you should always pass the format to parse unless *endDate* is a Date or moment object. `new Date(dateToCompare)` doesn't work because [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is strip out the time and just compare the dates, don't do a string conversion; just set the hour, minutes, and seconds on your Date objects to zero before making your date comparison.

```js
let foo = new Date();
console.log(foo);// date includes time
foo.setHours(0); foo.setMinutes(0); foo.setSeconds(0);
console.log(foo) // date set to midnight (in your timezone)
```